# How to set the value for textfield in JSP from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to generate a random number when user selects on the "Generate" button and set the value in the textfield. How do i set the "output variable" in the "randomNum" textfield.

HTML codes:

```
<form action="submit.jsp" method= "post" name="privateKey">
            Random String: <input type="text" name="randomNum" onkeyleave="generate()">
            <input type="button" name="generate" value="Generate!" >

</form>
```

Javascript:

```
     function generate() {
           char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           Random random = new Random();
           for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
               char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
               sb.append(c);
           }
           String output = sb.toString();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

HTML:

```
<form action="submit.jsp" method= "post" name="privateKey">
            Random String: <input type="text" name="randomNum" id="demo" onkeyleave="generate()">
            <input type="button" name="generate" value="Generate!" >

</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function generate() {
           char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           Random random = new Random();
           for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
               char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
               sb.append(c);
           }
            document.getElementById("demo").value = sb.toString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

set an id for input text:

```
 <input id="randomtxt" type="text" name="randomNum" onkeyleave="generate()">
```

the last line in the function should be changed:

```
 document.getElementById("randomtxt").value= sb.toString();
```

Comment: @ManProgrammer why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester because you didn't use `output` String.